# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED but DNS seems to be valid

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cname-record

I have an Azure VM runnig docker with an Nginx container and dns config with CNAME entries pointing to that Azure VM. The Website is not available in browsers (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in Chrome). The Azure website itself is available.

Working website: http://test-plattform.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/

Not working website: http://dev.flamplattform.ch

DNS Checker shows valid CNAME resolution: https://dnschecker.org/#CNAME/dev.flamplattform.ch

.nginx config

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    log_not_found off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # some security headers here...

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name dev.flamplattform.ch test-plattform.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app:80;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have DNS issues, your webserver config has nothing to do iwth it.  The CNAME propogation is OK per that website, but if you change to an A record then some are propogated and some aren't.  On my own caching name servers (bind9) and on `1.1.1.1` you are showing as NXDOMAIN.  When I query your registered name servers (ns1.hosttech.ch) directly I get a REFUSED response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CNAME records for `www` and `dev` have an obvious typo.

```
dev.flamplattform.ch.   3600    IN  CNAME   test-plattform.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/.
www.flamplattform.ch.   3600    IN  CNAME   test-plattform.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/.
```

Remove the erroneous `/` from the end of the record.

Your DNS provider should have never allowed you to even create these records, but apparently they don't validate input very well...

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't belive I missed that...

Comment: Your records look correct now, but you may still have to wait 3600 seconds due to DNS caching (which is often incorrectly called "propagation").